# Flex item shrinking even with flex-shrink: 0

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The `flex-shrink` property specifies how the item will shrink relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container so when I give a `flex-shrink` of `0` it shouldn't shrink but it shrinks.

```css
#content {
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.box1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<h4>it shinks with a flex-shrink of 0</h4>
<div id="content">
  <div class="box" style="background-color:red;">A</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;">C</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:brown;">D</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:lightgreen;">E</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:brown;">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://cssreference.io/property/flex-shrink/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified enough width for the flex items to overflow the container (`nowrap`) or the line (`wrap`). Therefore, `flex-shrink` isn't being called into action. If the flex items are wide enough, they will overflow the container or wrap, and not shrink, as you expect.

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 0 150px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.box1 {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<h4>it shinks with a flex-shrink of 0</h4>
<div id="content">
  <div class="box" style="background-color:red;">A</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;">C</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:brown;">D</div>
  <div class="box1" style="background-color:lightgreen;">E</div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:brown;">F</div>
</div>
```